# Lightbox close button behind Video on iPad (Safari and WebView)

Tags: javascript, ipad, webkit, lightbox, html5-video

Does anybody know why the close button of the Lightbox is behind the Video and not on foreground on the iPad (Safari browser and WebView in App)?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYI9w.png

With other Elements (Image gallery, Text / HTML) the close button is rendered correctly.

On Safari with Mac OS X (not iOS) the close button works correctly as well with video.

The Lightbox is standard and the video is embedded with the video tag.

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `position: relative` on it; that can make a difference sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, the video tag works kind of like a plugin. For a long time, [browsers always put plugins above all content independent of zindex](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html). I'm guessing the same thing is happening here.